# Scala Spark eclipse build error

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I am using

- Scala 2.10.4
- Spark Core 2.10-1.6.1
- hadoop core 1.2.1
- jackson core 2.4.4

I have below error in Problems tab in eclipse

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   error while loading RDDOperationScope, Missing dependency 'bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDDOperationScope.class refers to term annotation in package com.fasterxml.jackson which is not available. It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling RDDOperationScope.class.', required by C:\Users\username\Downloads\spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.jar(org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope.class) FirstScala      Unknown Scala Problem

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved after adding Jackson annotations.